# time.h: differences between linux and windows

Tags: c, time.h

Are there any differences between the functions defined in `time.h` related to the underlying operating system? I mean do they act the same way under windows or linux?

For example: does `clock()` return a processor tick count associated with the process in both windows and linux?

Comment: The `clock` function is utterly non-conforming on Windows, but this is a minor issue since the function is not useful for anything meaningful.

Comment: what does `clock` do in windows exactly?

Comment: Windows doesn't implement clock(), it is a detail of your C runtime implementation.  Which does what the C standard says it should do, assuming your CRT is not wildly unusual.  CLOCKS_PER_SEC is usually 1000 and the approximation is usually accurate to 16 msec.